# @property definitions with ARC: strong or retain?

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, nsmanagedobject, retain

Using Xcode 4.2 and ARC, I notice that the auto-generated code for an `NSManagedObject` still reads like this for properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * someString;
```

1) Shouldn't `retain` now be replace with `strong` or `weak`?

2) Why does the auto-generated code still use `retain`

3) What is the correct replacement for `retain` in this property statement?

I'm currently debugging a problem using `NSFetchRequest`, and I thought this might be the source of the problem. Thoughts?

Answer (score 110):

> 1) Shouldn't retain now be replace with strong or weak?

No. You cannot replace retain with weak; they are different. And strong is a 100% synonym for retain; they are identical. You can use either, so there is no "should" here. You can replace retain with strong if you like, but you don't have to.

> 2) Why does the auto-generated code still use retain

Why not? See (1). retain is correct so there is no problem.

> 3) What is the correct replacement for retain in this property statement?

There is no need to replace retain.

> I'm currently debugging a problem using NSFetchRequest, and I thought this might be the source of the problem. Thoughts?

It isn't.

Comment: I'd posit though, for a community as obsessed (and rightly so!) with standards and compliance to Apple Way(s), seeing retain in only synthesized models is subpar. I change to strong just to be pedantic. For one, makes ack-ing a large project for improper syntax a bit easier, amongst a half dozen other little things.

Comment: Not sure exactly what emotional architecture is. Can you provide an example in the "cold, clear light of day?" ;-) false and NO are synonyms, but we use NO by convention in Objective-C. There are reasons for being consistent; to be inconsistent is fine, but the burden of proving worthiness is on the one breaking convention, not the one adhering to it.

Comment: With all due respect, @EricGoldberg does have a point: convention matters. And because you're going to be `__strong` in other places in your code (there is no `__retain`) you might want to switch to using `strong` for consistency. This is similar to indenting your code in a consistent fashion, even though the code will run fine without this.

Comment: @Yar - I don't disagree. In my own code I have in fact replaced retain with strong everywhere. But this is for aesthetic reasons. The fact remains that what I said is right: strong and retain are absolutely interchangeable. The OP's question was whether retain *should* be replaced by *strong*. My answer was: no. Of course he *may* do so, and most people *will* do so. But as Hume showed, you can't get from "is" to "ought". :)

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question was whether leaving retain as retain under ARC could be the source of the problem. I don't see how that could be.

Comment: @matt: if you look at my original comment, the one where you accused me of coding "emotionally" (whatever that is), you'll see that I use the words "posit" and "just to be pedantic." I in fact suggest "ought" and not "is."

Comment: ALL OF PROGRAMMING is about idiom. There are no other issues.  All programming is a synonym, the whole engineering practice of programming is about using the current idiom, so as to add value to the code for the client.

Comment: It should be remembered though that Assign and Weak are not the same, as Assign can actually cause you to crash an app where weak will be handled by ARC properly. For example check out the UIWebView Delegate and see how you have to nil out the delegate otherwise the app will crash.

Answer (score 40):

To answer all three questions in one: `retain` and `strong` are synonymous with each other, so both are correct. [The documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) states

> `retain` implies `__strong` ownership
>
> `strong` implies `__strong` ownership

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did read the Apple document on ARC.  I do understand that retain translates to strong.  However, this does not explain why the code that is automatically generated by Xcode when create new NSManagedObject(s) will give you @property (nonatomic, retain)

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, that explains it perfectly. The code that Xcode creates is correct since retain works just as strong, so where is your question?

Comment: If you run the ARC refactoring on your project, it will convert all those `retain`s to `strong`s. So my impression is that `strong` is the preferred attribute, but the NSManagedObject generator has not been updated. But that's just a guess; maybe no one at Apple considers the distinction important.

Answer (score 4):

Before ARC, you have to 'release' an object which is retained. That mean retain has counter part. After ARC you don't need to release. So use strong. Its a visual clue that you don't need to call release.

Answer (score 3):

"retain" is equals to "strong".

"strong" is used for example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * someString;
```

And "__strong" is used for example:

```
-(void) someMethod
{
    __strong NSString* vStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"some string"];
}
```

On Apple Docs. says:

Property Attributes

The keywords weak and strong are introduced as new declared property attributes, as shown in the following examples.

```
// The following declaration is a synonym for: @property(retain) MyClass *myObject;
property(strong) MyClass *myObject;
```

Apple doc. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html