# What's the difference between 'weak' and 'assign' in delegate property declaration

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, delegates, properties

Whats the difference between this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id  <SubClassDelegate> delegate;
```

and this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id  <SubClassDelegate> delegate;
```

I want to use property for delegates.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The only difference between `weak` and `assign` is that if the object a `weak` property points to is deallocated, then the value of the `weak` pointer will be set to `nil`, so that you never run the risk of accessing garbage. If you use `assign`, that won't happen, so if the object gets deallocated from under you and you try to access it, you will access garbage.

For Objective-C objects, if you're in an environment where you can use `weak`, then you should use it.

Comment: Do you know why some of the Cocoa Touch framework classes are still using assign for delegates? For example, the delegate of [UISearchDisplayController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchDisplayController/delegate) is still assign. Why wasn't it ever updated?

Comment: @Pwner looks like it has been deprecated in iOS 8.0

Comment: Here's a non-deprecated example: even `UITableView` has `assign` for its delegate: `@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;`

Comment: @ChrisNolet Because probably they are still using MRC (Manual Reference Counting) internally.

Comment: As of today, the example of UITableView's delegate is now: @property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
So that is no longer a valid example.