# Is it possible or necessary to synthesize/release weak property in manual retain-release mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

For example, I subclass `UIView`, in which a weak property called `myString` is defined. There is an error message for `@synthesize myString = _myString;` statement: `Semantic Issue: @synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode`.

The `MyUIView.h` file:

```
@interface MyUIView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *myString;

@end
```

The `MyUIView.m` file:

```
#import "MyUIView.h"

@implementation MyUIView

@synthesize myString = _myString; // This statement causes an error whose message is Semantic Issue: @synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_myString release];

    [super dealloc];
}

// Other methods

@end
```

Then I removed the `@synthesize myString = _myString;` and there goes another error for this statement `[_myString release];` as `Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier '_text'`

If it's not necessary to synthesize nor release a weak property like `myString` above, should I re-write the code like this:

The `MyUIView.h` file:

```
@interface MyUIView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *myString;

@end
```

The `MyUIView.m` file:

```
#import "MyUIView.h"

@implementation MyUIView

- (void)dealloc
{        
    [super dealloc];
}

// Other methods

@end
```

Comment: Read the error. `@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC`. That file is not being compiled with ARC enabled.

Comment: Is there a special reason that you declare the property as weak?

Comment: a property called label but is not a UILabel: poor naming.

Comment: To @MartinR, the above code is made by another person, I guess it's written in ARC. But I want to change it into manual retain-release style.

Comment: To @vikingosegundo, Property name changed from `label` to `myString` :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`weak` is a valid property attribute only when ARC (or GC) is enabled.

You can either switch to ARC (strongly advisable) or use an `assign` or `unsafe_unretained` attribute instead, at the cost of losing the benefit of a `weak` reference (see [Whats the difference between 'weak' and 'assign' in delegate property declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428500/whats-the-difference-between-weak-and-assign-in-delegate-property-declaratio))

That being said, I think both `assign` and `weak` won't accomplish anything desirable in the specific case.

Unless you really want to avoid a strong reference to that string, the appropriate property declaration would go as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
```

On why `copy` and not `retain` (or `strong`), you can read [NSString property: copy or retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain)

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` (and any other class that is immutable with a mutable subclass) should be synthesized to `copy`.

```
@property (copy) NSString *myString;
```

the first comment: Yes. (nonatomic, copy) is fine.

the second comment: You don't need to, it is assumed as well in modern objective-c syntax. There will be a `_myString` ivar created either way. Yes you need to release `_myString` if you use `copy`

Comment: It makes always sense to use "copy" with a NSString property. That is independent of ARC vs. Manual Reference Counting.

Comment: To @JesseNaugher, Can I use `nonatomic` in the same time with `copy`, as `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;`?

Comment: To @JesseNaugher, If I use `copy` attribute for the property `myString`, do I need to `@synthesize myString = _myString` (I know this is default, so I mean will there be an default `_myString` ivar made for the property with copy attribute?) And if there is `_myString` ivar made, do I need to `[_myString release]` in the `dealloc` method?

Comment: *"properties are assumed to be nonatomic unless otherwise specified"* - That is not correct. The default is "atomic" (unfortunately).

Comment: To @JesseNaugher, In your first sentence, **"and any other class that is immutable with a mutable subclass"**, do you mean that, for example, if I want a property in the class of `NSArray`, it should be synthesized to `copy`, because there is `NSMutableArray`. Then why it should always be `copy` if there exists "mutable" subclass?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain/388002#388002

Comment: @congliu the fact that a mutable subclass exist is precisely why you use `copy`. You don't wan the client to be able to modify the collection after it has been passed to you. `copy` solves the case in which you accept a `NSArray` but the client provides a `NSMutableArray`. It's also worth noting that `copy` on a `NSArray` returns the array itself, instead of a copy, so you can have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: @JesseNaugher by the way I think your post, as currently stands, doesn't answer the question. You are not explaining why weak variables cannot be synthesized in MRC, which is what the OP asked.

Comment: @JesseNaugher btw please use the comment system to reply to comments instead of editing your answers to include those.