# Passing string back in popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UIViewController(1), I press on a view in that controller and it then push's another UIViewController(2) with a full screen UITableView in it.

I then press on a cell in the UITableView and want to pass back to UIViewController(1) a string in the UITableView. I have tried using the below delegete method but it doesn't work, please can somebody advise.

```
UIViewController2.h
@protocol SecondDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) secondViewControllerDismissed:(NSString *)stringForFirst;
@end

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
{
    id myDelegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SecondDelegate> myDelegate;
@end
```

and

```
UIViewController2.m (inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath)
    [self.myDelegate secondViewControllerDismissed:@"the string I'm passing"];
```

and

```
UIViewController1.h
import "ViewController2.h"
    @interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <SecondDelegate>

@end
```

and

```
UIViewController1.m
- (void)secondViewControllerDismissed:(NSString *)stringForFirst
{
    NSString *myString = stringForFirst; 
    self.myLabel.text = myString;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Where does something not work as intended? Did you actually set the `myDelegate` property? You should maybe change your `@propery` to `(weak)`... and remove the `id myDelegate` line inside the `@interface`

Comment: My question is in the last piece of code, why does self.myLabel.text != myString. It doesn't pass the string

Comment: The function is not getting called?

Comment: Where do you present ViewController2?

Comment: when i tap on a view in ViewController1, it performs a segue to ViewController2

Comment: - (void)secondViewControllerDismissed:(NSString *)stringForFirst   
is never called in ViewController1

Comment: whilst debugging with breakpoint i find the above method is never called in ViewController1, do I just need to call it on viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- remove `id myDelegate;` inside your `@interface ViewController2`
- change your `@property (nonatomic, assign) id...` to `@property (nonatomic, weak) id...`, that is just safer (see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428500/whats-the-difference-between-weak-and-assign-in-delegate-property-declaratio))

Regarding your question: you present the view via a segue!? Therefore you need to overwrite the `prepareForSegue` method, extract the `destinationViewController` from the `segue` and set its `delegate` property to `self`. Without that, your ViewController2 never gets a valid delegate set. All that needs to be done in the viewController **presenting** the `ViewController2`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourCustomSegueIdentifier"]) {
        ViewController2 *controller = (ViewController2*)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller. myDelegate = self;
    }
}
```

Either set an identifier of your segue in the storyboard and use the same identifier in the ode above or remove the if all together (unclean).

Comment: yes I present via a segue, please could you provide example code for your suggestion?

Comment: I am getting "Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'

Comment: i added it in ViewController1.m

Comment: and it is getting called when you touch a button or do *something* to show ViewController2 ?

Comment: yes, prepareForSegue is called automatically when you call performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: I changed it to set the `myDelegate`, was a minor typo... Does it work now?

Comment: HAZAR! Much internet love to you! Many Thanks

Comment: Why remove `nonatomic` from the properly declaration? Does it need to be `atomic` (the default)?

Comment: @rmaddy well, you are right, atomic/nonatomic slipped by, I primarily wanted him to write weak and not to include assign... will update.