# how can find where is object is released in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

i am calling this method from parentclass

imagepicker.m

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)thePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)imageInfo
{

     UIImage *imag = [imageInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imag,0.1);

    [parentviewcontroller requestToParentWithImage:imageData];
}
```

Here parentviewcontroller is declared in imagepicker.h

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIViewController<SmartretailDelegate> *parentviewcontroller;
```

TASKLISTDATA.M

```
IMAG=[IMAGEPICKER alloc]init];
IMAG.parentviewcontroller=self;
```

my question is parentviewcontroller is not allocated.where is it deallocated/crash?

Answer (score 1):

'strong' attribute indicates that the parentviewcontroller object is retained and it will be deallocated when imagePicker object gets deallocated. For more information refer this link '[Objective-C ARC: strong vs retain and weak vs assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign)'.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to learn a bit more about how [ARC (or Automated Reference Counting) works](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ios-5-automatic-reference-counting-arc).

When your "`IMAG`" object is released by ARC, the ***strong*** reference to the parentviewcontroller gets released as well.

Comment: i didn't use ARC in my project

Comment: are you *sure* of that?  If you didn't, then "`strong`" in your "`@property`" declaration would throw a compiler error or warning.

Comment: @property(strong,nonatomic)UIViewController<SmartretailDelegate> *parentviewcontroller; i gave like this

Comment: initially i gave retain instead of strong

Comment: how to rerain the parentviewcontroller. can u suggest me

Comment: Just switch your project to ARC dude