# populating NSMutableArray not working

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Hi I have an instance variable NSMutable Array.

I declare it as such

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *list;
```

In viewDidLoad I instantiate it.

```
self.list = [NSMutableArray array];
```

I then make a string consisting of the text of text fields and add it to the array.

```
NSString * lines = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@", [self.crabText text], [self.trawlText text], [self.trapText text], [self.vesselText text], [self.lengthText text]];

    [self.list addObject:lines];
```

This is apart of a function which will keep on adding new values of the text fields into the array.

I display the contents of the array with

```
int i;
    int count;
    for (i = 0, count = [self.list count]; i < count; i = i + 1)
    {
        NSString *element = [self.list objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"The element at index %d in the array is: %@", i, element); // just replace the %@ by %d
    }
```

However, the app crashes when I try to print the contents of the array and I get

EXC_BAD_ACCESS_CODE

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your declaration like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *list; // strong and not assign
```

Initialize your array in your viewDidLoad :

```
self.list = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and add one by one your string :

```
[self.list addObject:self.crabText.text];
[self.list addObject:self.trawlText.text];
....
```

Next, modify your for loop :

```
for (int i = 0, i < self.list.count, i++)
{
    NSLog(@"The element at index %d in the array is: %@", i, [self.list objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Comment: Changing assign to strong did it. But why?

Comment: because assign is for primitive variable. But, have a look here to understand how to use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to declare the array this way in your header file

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray* list;
}
@end
```

Then in the ViewDidLoad

```
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Everything else can be done just as Jordan said. Though I'm not sure if there is a difference in performance between either implementation.