# iOS7 is there a reason to use assign instead of weak for properties?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, strong-parameters

I've encountered several "message sent to deallocated instance" bugs within my app and traced them to the use of

`@property(nonatomic,assign)NSObject* object;`

Replacing them with

`@property(nonatomic,weak)BuffCollection* buffCollection;`

solves the problem. **Should I define all of my properties where I don't want to use `strong` to be using `weak` instead of `assign`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres a great explanation of all the different property attributes [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign)

If you are using ARC, the basics are to use strong for obj-c objects you want to retain, weak for obj-c objects you don't want to retain and assign for non-objective-c (so C) primatives. Strong is default.