# NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults - What does this code do in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to understand some code and I am wondering what this code does on OS X Application:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain]
```

It's set up as a variable. I am wondering if it gathers information about the system. I am trying to run an application inside virtual machine, but it won't let me and I am trying to analyse the code to see why, but I don't know Objective-C.

Comment: It is nonsensical as far as I can tell.  standardUserDefaults is a singleton, and therefore wouldn't be retained even in the strange circumstance of assigning it somewhere.

Comment: @danh Why is assigning it somewhere a strange circumstance?

Comment: It can be accessed any place with `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.

Comment: Practically the code does nothing at all except unnecessarily increasing the retain counter of the `standardUserDefaults` singleton.

Comment: @danh calling `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` once and storing the result in a variable runs faster. This isn't strange, it's efficient if you want to get or set a lot of preferences.

Answer (score 0):

So before ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) was a thing, you would see `retain` and `release` everywhere.

When you allocate an object, you had to `retain` it, to increment the retain count.  And if you ever called `release`, you would decrement the retain count.  If the retain count ever hit 0, the object was released, `-dealloc` would be called

Now with ARC, the `retain` and `release` instructions are compiled in, based off of attributes of your object (`strong`, `weak`) you can read more about that here: [Objective-C ARC: strong vs retain and weak vs assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign)

Anyways point being that your line there, as danh said, does nothing.  Because `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` is a singleton, there is no point in incrementing the retain count, because there's no threat of it being released from under you.
Although I don't think it is the weirdest thing to assign the `standardUserDefaults` to a local pointer, it would be just as effective to access the singleton every time you needed the standard defaults

Comment: No, calling `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` every time isn't just as effective. Calling a method isn't effective.