# what is the difference between strong (in LLVM) and retain( in GCC)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

what is the difference between strong (in LLVM compiler) and retain( in GCC compiler) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C ARC: strong vs retain and weak vs assign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign)

Comment: See also [@property definitions with ARC: strong or retain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796476/property-definitions-with-arc-strong-or-retain)

Answer (score 10):

`strong` is a new feature in iOS 5 Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) which behave the same as `retain` in iOS 4. [Referenced Article.](http://jonathanhui.com/ios-5-programming-xcode)

Also, check out this other SO question: [@property definitions with ARC: strong or retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796476/property-definitions-with-arc-strong-or-retain)

Answer (score -1):

strong is a new keyword that was introduced along with arc (automatic reference counting).  There are a bazillion articles about it if you search google, including this one http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/11/27/the-jungle-part-4-automatic-reference-counting/

Comment: yes, i am aware of strong keyword features. But i just want to know how strong(LLVM) differs from retain(GCC) ?