# Whats the difference between strong and retain?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between strong (in LLVM) and retain( in GCC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299200/what-is-the-difference-between-strong-in-llvm-and-retain-in-gcc)

I can see everywhere that we can use strong property instead of retain in the latest object c programming. But, i want to know that how much it differs between strong and retain and what are the added advantage with strong than retain, so Apple released strong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Its entirely semantic (afaik) to the way ARC and non-ARC projects work.  Apple would prefer everyone use ARC and is pushing in that direction.

In a non-ARC project "strong" will act as "retain".  In an ARC project "retain" might work if clang doesn't flag an error (i dont use ARC), but theres a subtlety in the description.

Retain says - Im holding on to this object, until Im ready to release it, strong says (hey ARC treat this as a retained object and insert some generated code in my dealloc method to be released when the autorelease pool drains).

As far as I know thats the only difference, its conceptual and if you are in happy ARC land you should not really have to care, unless it breaks :(

Comment: And weak is equivalent to assign. i.e. an object reference that is not retained. If you are on a modern system, this has the added benefit of being zeroed. i.e. If you have a weak reference to an object that is deleted, then the reference will be set to `nil` so you don't need to worry about sending a message to an object that has been deallocated.