# Enabling ARC in a single file through compiler flags?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I had an application in which i am enabling ARC in individual files by using

> copiler flag -
>
> > fobjc-arc in the implementation files of the view controller.When i am enabling this no release or autorelease is available on that m
> >     file.and all working fine.

But i had a serious doubt about the fact that what are the changes need to be done to the .h file of that class.

> still i am using the
>
> > retain properties as earlier with the case of nonARC.
>
> Can anybody knew what are the changes need to be done to the .h file
>   in this case.is there any requirement of strong properties instead of
>   retain.can anybody had guide me on these facts?

Comment: no, as strong works same as retain.

Comment: @Aman Aggarwal Are u sure that it will make no difference.

Comment: yup i am sure  chk these links 1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299200/what-is-the-difference-between-strong-in-llvm-and-retain-in-gcc  2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262535/explanation-of-strong-and-weak-storage-in-ios5

Comment: @AmanAggarwal i am using LLVM compiler 4.1 with iOS 6 as the base sdk and iOS 5 as the deployment target.still its ok to use retain?.pardon me if its troubling you ,i was still very much confused on this subject.

Comment: yes it is. Though to get a full proof answer you can test it on device :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, in header file, you'd better use ARC modifiers, for example, strong for retain.