# Automatically created NSManagedObject subclasses don't use ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

My project is ARC enabled (the build settings have Objective-C Reference Counting set to YES). There are no file exceptions to this, it is enabled project wide. (Latest stable version of Xcode).

When I create an NSManagedObject subclass via File > New for a Core Data entity, the generated header uses the following in its property declarations:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)
```

But 'retain' is not ARC!! Is this a bug, or is there something I'm missing or not understanding? There are no build warnings - if this is a bug though, how can I remedy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`retain` is a synonym for `strong`. So it is perfectly valid to use `retain` or `strong` in this case.

[For more detail check out this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796476/property-definitions-with-arc-strong-or-retain)

Answer (score 0):

`retain` is a valid property declaration in ARC:  See the clang [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) on it