# NSManagedObject model generated by Xcode use retain property in ARC project

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timeStamp;

@end
```

There is no compile error here. Why can use `retain` here? Should I replace it with `strong`?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796476/property-definitions-with-arc-strong-or-retain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strong` is 100% synonymous with `retain`, so you don't need to replace it unless you want to. XCode generates it because, again, it's identical to `strong`.

That said, it would be nice if it used `strong` for consistency's sake. Apple's docs generally say if ARC == use `strong`, so it'd be nice if they did the same!