# Setting strong references objects to nil with ARC enabled?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, strong-references

I am developing an iPhone app with ARC option enabled. i am creating IBOutlets in .h files which are connected from file owners icon to .xib elements.for eg.

```
IBOutlet UIButton *bt;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *bt;
```

in .m file, i am doing

```
@synthesize bt;
```

Is there a need to explicitly set `bt` to nil in `viewDidUnload` method? i.e. `self.bt = nil;` in `viewDidUnload`?

Also, do I need to write `dealloc` method with ARC option enabled? When should I make IBOutlets elements as strong and weak references with ARC enabled?

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between the need to put your outlets to nil in `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`

Having ARC means you don't need to write that in your `dealloc` method (it gets done automatically), however the `viewDidUnload` method serves another purpose, and it is to free memory that the application isn't using when a memory warning occurs.
`dealloc` is still needed in some cases, for example, when your class is registered for a notification, or when your class is someone else's delegate and you don't want some glitchy callback giving you a bad access

When you get a memory warning, all the `UIViewControllers` not being displayed will unload their view and call that method to free up memory. If you are still retaining outlets (like buttons, tables and etc) they will not get released, thus, killing the purpose of the viewDidUnload method.

Comment: "he viewDidUnload method serves another purpose, and it is to free memory that the application isn't using when a memory warning occurs" NOPE. For that purpose there's didReceiveMemoryWarning.

Comment: They both get called on memory warning, though the correct place to set your outlets to nil is in viewDidUnload ... it's even noted on the method when you create a new UIViewController subclass!!

Answer (score 2):

When using ARC there is no need to use modifiers like `retain` or `copy`, for example. That kind of memory managment is done automatically using the `strong` and `weak` modifiers.

You also don't have to worry about writing `dealloc` methods.

`strong` is *kind of* the equivalent of `retain`, so you should mark your outlets with it

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *bt;
```

That's the way interface builder creates them by default.

I won't go into detail about their semantic differences, but you should really have a look at [Apple's guide on transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) if you want to know what's going on and read about the specifics of `strong` and `weak` modifiers.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, interface builder creates outlets with `weak` by default.

**EDIT 2:**
`strong` and `retain` are indeed 100% identical. (thanks to @Adam)

**EDIT 3:**
You set your pointers to `nil` to avoid getting any `message sent to deallocated instance` or `BAD_ACCESS_EXCEPTION` errors.

If you are actually using ARC, you should make your outlets `(nonatomic, weak)` instead of `(nonatomic, strong)`. By using the `weak` zeroing pointers, what the compiler does is automatically set your outlets to `nil` when nothing else references them.

So, summing up, if you **don't** use `weak` properties, you *should* set your pointers to nil.

Comment: thanks for your answer..one thing more..is it against the apple guidelines if i use retain instead of strong with ARC options enabled?because i have already used @property(nonatomic,retain) at many places.

Comment: i'm pretty sure `retain` is 100% the same as `strong`. so there should be no problem using it

Comment: ya its not creating any problem but i am unsure whether using it ARC option makes it against apple guidelines or not??

Comment: i don't think it's against any guideline. if it were the compiler would bitch about it. but if you really want to be consistent with conventions and best practises, you should change it to `strong`. after all, is just replacing a few words. have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796476/property-definitions-with-arc-strong-or-retain

Comment: @abhishekbehl Core Data autogenerated classes have properties declared with `retain` even if your project uses ARC. So no, it is not against anything. [Apple says they are synonyms](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @Adam..thnks..even i think their shoudnt be a problem as apple says they are synonyms.

Comment: @abhishekbehl Glad to help :) I have submitted a couple of iOS apps to the App Store. They all use ARC and Core Data. I have never changed `retain` to `strong` in the generated code and never got any of them rejected.

Comment: @Adam..hey thts gr8..whch all apps do u have??and can u tell me the list of points which i need to keep in mind while developing an app with ARC..??

Comment: @Adam..in my .xib files..i have created IBoutlets with @property(nonatomic,retain) and ARC enabled..so do i need to set them to nil in viewDidUnload method??Any sort of help would be great..:)