# Getting error for passed in UserId in tab controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am not sure why I keep getting this error, I do pass the userId from the profile view controller on a button click with a push:

```
TotalTabController *userTabView = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"userTabView"];
    userTabView.userProfileId = userId;

    NSLog(@"the user tota tab is %@", userId);
    userTabView.userProfileName = profileName;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:userTabView animated:NO];
```

The NSLog prints out the correct userID, and then I have it added to the tab controller in the .h file like so:

```
@interface TotalTabController : UITabBarController {
    NSString *userProfileId, *userProfileName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userProfileId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userProfileName;
```

And in the .m file like so:

```
@synthesize userProfileId, userProfileName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"the  tab loaded and is %@", userProfileId);
}
```

but the NSLog prints out null in the .m file...

Then I call it in one of the tab views .m file like so:

```
userProfileId = [(TotalTabController*)self.tabBarController userProfileId];
```

And then get this error:

The error is:

```
2014-05-17 11:49:04.667 Example[1108:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01e291e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01ba88e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01def376 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 390
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01e1cc29 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 73
    4   Example                               0x00012233 -[CreatedCollectionViewController getCreatedNames] + 419
    5   Example                               0x0001202b -[CreatedCollectionViewController viewDidLoad] + 123
    6   UIKit                               0x0098733d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    7   UIKit                               0x009875d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x009bf11f -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 407
    9   UIKit                               0x009be943 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 63
    10  UIKit                               0x009babed -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 281
    11  UIKit                               0x009baacc -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 180
    12  UIKit                               0x009b7e30 __87-[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:]_block_invoke + 43
    13  UIKit                               0x008ce81f +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
    14  UIKit                               0x009b7cd5 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 247
    15  UIKit                               0x009b8ae9 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 148
    16  UIKit                               0x0098b04b -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 448
    17  UIKit                               0x0098b548 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 114
    18  UIKit                               0x0099c105 -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 199
    19  UIKit                               0x009a1a5e -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1062
    20  UIKit                               0x009ae8f7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    21  UIKit                               0x009af4e9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    22  UIKit                               0x00af00d1 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    23  UIKit                               0x008d7964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    24  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bba82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    25  QuartzCore                          0x0455045a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    26  QuartzCore                          0x04544244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    27  QuartzCore                          0x045440b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    28  QuartzCore                          0x044aa7fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    29  QuartzCore                          0x044abb85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    30  QuartzCore                          0x045695b0 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
    31  UIKit                               0x008669bb _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 13095
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x01db277f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x01db210b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x01dcf1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x01dce9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x01dce7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x03be85ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x03be842b GSEventRun + 104
    39  UIKit                               0x00868f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    40  Stand                               0x00013a3d main + 141
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x02575701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The ultimate goal is to pass the userID from the profile.m file to the tab controller and allow each tab to have access to the userID, not sure what I am doing wrong, if someone can notice the error or let me know how I can have it so that it is not null and accessible?

**Update**
I am thinking maybe it has to do with not being able to push a tabcontroller according to apple's guidelines, could that be the case? If so how do I go around it, or what options do I have?

Comment: look in [CreatedCollectionViewController getCreatedNames] you are inserting things into a dictionary... on of those things is nil

Comment: I know as I mentioned the reason it is null is because the item being called is null on being passed in, and not sure why...

Comment: toss an assert and break point in and work it backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the problem here is that you are trying to push tab bar controller in navigation controller but apple forbids it [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html) .So you can add the tabbar controller modally or create a custom tab bar in a view controller and push it

Comment: Well adding the self gives me an error saying expected (    and retain is the same as strong ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796476/property-definitions-with-arc-strong-or-retain

Comment: thn you can add a private property on the .m file. i don't have the mc now otherwise i ll be able to give the code

Comment: I included a property and tried to set it, but in the .m file the id is still showing up as null...

Comment: and don't use remove this line userProfileId = [(TotalTabController*)self.tabBarController userProfileId];

Comment: Does it print the value now?

Comment: Nope, the same thing null... everything the same

Comment: have you tried adding break point on this line userTabView.userProfileName = profileName; and check userTabView.userProfileName is not null?

Comment: Yeah, it passes in the name and the id, it somehow gets lost on the tab controller

Comment: You are pushing tabbarcontroller in navgationcontroller but it is not a good practice here is the apple documnetion link:https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html we always push navigation controller on tabbarcotroller, so that might be the problem in your case

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that could be it as you can see the update I posted above a while ago... so what are my options then?

Comment: You can show the tab bar Modally or you can create a custom tabbar in a view controller[preferable] and push it in your navigation controller

Comment: Ok so yeah the tab controller seems to have been the issue created a custom one and the id does get passed now.